# nasm segmentation fault when passing parameters to C function (x86_64 Assembly)

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, function-pointers, nasm

I am new to nasm and try to implement a code that passes two parameters (int 64bit) to a C code that applies a fold function on these variables.

I consider an array passed to *rdx*, an operator like + or - passed to *rdi* and the amount of array elements passed to *rsi* (int input) .The result of the first application of the function should be used as the first argument of the next application and so on.

Now nasm prints a seg fault when im trying to call the function again for the next array elements (it works when i only call the function once).I am not sure if it is because of the way i take specific elements from the array or because there is something missing. I have tried to push the arguments and then copy them by the stack pointer, but that ends up with the same error message. nasm assembly command: `nasm -f elf64 fold.nasm`
C compile command: `gcc -std=c99 -o fold fold.c fold.o`

```
global fold

section .text


jmp fold1

**prefold:**

xor r15,r15         
xor rbx,rbx         
xor rax,rax 

mov rax,[rdx]       ; take first array element to rax

mov rbx,[rdx+8]     ; 2nd to rbx

mov r15,8           

jmp fold1

**fold:**

jmp prefold

fold1:

mov r8,rdi              
;secure operator and length of array in r8,r9

mov r9,rsi

mov rdi,rax             
;the function pointer requires the arguments beeing stored in rdi,rsi 

mov rsi,[rdx]

add r15,8

mov rbx, [rdx+r15]

call r8

dec r9

mov rdi,r8      
; restore operator and decremented array length

mov rsi,r9

cmp r9,1    

jne fold1

ret
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using Valgrind to pinpoint where the problem is?

Comment: I have not used Valgrind yet. I tried to find the problem via gdb, but it was not really helpful to me in this concrete problem.

Comment: You should consider at least looking over the [64-bit System V Calling Convention](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) . In particular a list of the callee preserved registers. You are using registers that need to be preserved in your function. See Figure 3.4: Register Usage .

Comment: I have changed the registers that needed to be preserved to not callee preserved registers, but it i still get the same error message.

Comment: Second thing to be aware of is when you call via _R8_ - if that is a function using the same calling convention then you have to be wary of all the registers that the function will destroy and that you rely on being the same across the call.

Comment: The function does use the same calling convention. I will save the registers now that I would need for the next calls before getting to the first call. Can you tell me if the way i try to take the array elements is actually possible/correct (using a register like a digit to take the first (rdx+(reg=8)) then second (rdx+(reg=16)) ...) array element  ? At this point,what alternates could I try ?